# running windows commands remotely

Tags: windows

I'm trying to run a command remotely.
Here is what I've tried

wmic /node:"my_server" /user:my_username /password:my_pass process call create "cmd.exe \c dir C:>C:\temp\x.txt"

I can see the process id returned and I see a terminal running on the remote machine with that process id and that process is just stuck and the output x.txt is not generated.
Any idea how to make it work?
Any idea why the process is running but not doing anything?
My goal is to get the output back so it is not necessary to write to a file.

Comment: You need `cmd.exe /c` - normal slash, not backslash.

Comment: Thanks. That worked.

Comment: @PakUula any idea how to run it with admin privileges?

Comment: Which of them? local `wmic` or remote `cmd`?

Comment: Sorry, almost all my life went in Unix/Linux world, and I'm complete dummy in the world of administering Windows ...